# Setting three different font size of a container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 200px container, centered with margin: 0 auto. In the container is a marquee width the long text that scrolls.

My goal is to set the font size of the text that appears inside the marquee to 3em (zoomed), and then the text that overflows set to 1em.

Basically, I want to have a zoomed text inside marquee. Use of jQuery is welcome.

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="container" style="width: 200px; margin: 0 auto">
     <marquee style="display: inline">Let's assume this goes outsize the div INSIDE DIV CONTAINER and then outside container</marquee>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "text that overflows"?

Comment: `marquee` is not only *deprecated*, it's *[obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete)* nowadays.

Comment: The marquee text that is outside the 200px div container.

Comment: I understand marquee is deprecated, I still need it for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make a text scrolling with and effect of two layers?

As already commented: do not use marquee or scrolling text, really noone wants to see a running text line nowadays

If you really want to do it here is an example. The idea is that the text in the background has double the size of the one in the front and runs 2x faster

```css
.outer {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.marque1 {
  font-size:40px;
  width:400px;
  position:absolute;
  left:-100px;
  top:0;
  line-height:90px;
  color:#999;
}
.marque2 {
  font-size:20px;
  width:200px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  line-height:100px;
  color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<marquee class="marque1" scrollamount="10">THIS IS SOME TEXT THAT SCROLL OVERLAYED</marquee>
<marquee class="marque2" scrollamount="5">THIS IS SOME TEXT THAT SCROLL OVERLAYED</marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really good. But I was trying to do is: Big text (visible inside and hidden outside). Small red text (hidden when in the box, visible when outside the box)